# Visualization of ActiveRecord / NHibernate Entity Model

Tags: nhibernate, visualization, castle-activerecord

Has anyone come across a tool to visualize an ActiveRecord / NHibernate entity model?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing I can think of is generating a class diagram from VisualStudio of your classes ....

Comment: No, I mean a tool that will create a diagram of the entity model, as all we currently have is code

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ActiveWriter](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=activewriter+activerecord).

Sample screenshot:

[alt text http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/1001/modelingsurface.png](http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/1001/modelingsurface.png)

Comment: But can ActiveWriter take our c# AR model classes and turn them into a diagram? I thought ActiveWriter was for diagram -> AR model classes